# PANDAS - Unique value counts in a muliti-indexed dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a multi-indexed data frame of the following form:

```
                X   Y  Z ..
 A    B    C   
a1   b1   T1   X1
          T2   X1
     b2   T3   X2
          T4   X2
          T5   X2
     b3   T6   X1

a2   b1   T7   X2
          T8   X2            
     b2   T9   X1
         T10   X1
     b3  T11   X1
     b4  T12   X3
```

A row is uniquely identified by the combination of `A` and `B` index values (`C` has no relevance- it's a time stamp).

**Question:** How can I find how many such combinations of `A` and `B` exist for each group of `X` values?

In this case, `A` and `B` are some attributes of a customer that composes a unique combination and `X` is a venue a purchase has been done. I want to know how many customers have purchased from a particular `X` venue.

i.e.,

```
x1 : 4 (a1b1, a1b3, a2b2, a2b3)
X2 : 2 (a1b2, a2b1)
X3 : 1 (a2b4)
```